# How can I allow a user to pan a map within a ListView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, google-maps, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a survey-style app in Xamarin.Forms in which I have numerous question types displayed in a ListView. For example, a single ListView would contain several cells that show either an Entry (text box), a Picker (combobox), or a Switch (checkbox).

In one question type, I ask the user whether their current GPS position is accurate relative to some landmark. To help them gauge the accuracy, I display a map within the cell itself. The issue I'm running into is that the user is unable to scroll the map vertically because Xamarin.Forms seems will scroll the entire ListView instead of just the map. Horizontal scrolling on the map seems to work fine, but as soon as a slight vertical motion is detected the ListView begins to move.

Is there a way to prevent the ListView from scrolling when the user is attempting to pan the map itself? Perhaps a way for the map to intercept the touch event?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a custom renderer for the ListView and disable it's scroll upon panning the map. 
Here is the information about custom renderers:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

for android, check this post:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37835/disable-scrollview-scrolling-on-android

for iOS, check this post:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56318/scrollview-horizontal-completely-disable-vertical-scroll